# Issue with LangChain Misclassifying gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct as Chat Model

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, gpt-3, py-langchain

OpenAI *deprecated* its **text-davinci-003** completion model. I've updated the model to **gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct**. I am encountering an issue with the **LangChain** where it **incorrectly classifies the gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct model as a chat model**. This is causing initialization problems in my code.

**Environment:**

```bash
python = "^3.10"
langchain = "^0.0.130"
```

OS: Ubuntu

**Expected Behavior:**

The expected behavior is that the gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct model should be recognized as a completion model by LangChain and initialized appropriately without warnings or errors.

**Actual Behavior:**

When attempting to initialize the gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct model, I receive warnings suggesting that this model is being misclassified as a chat model. The specific warnings are:

```bash
/home/mahdi/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-bRqVKcMN-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/llms/openai.py:169: UserWarning: You are trying to use a chat model. This way of initializing it is no longer supported. Instead, please use: `from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI`
/home/mahdi/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-bRqVKcMN-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/llms/openai.py:608: UserWarning: You are trying to use a chat model. This way of initializing it is no longer supported. Instead, please use: `from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
```

**My simplified code:**

```py
from langchain import OpenAI


llm = OpenAI({
            "model_name": "gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
            "temperature": 0.0,
            "top_p": 1,
            "openai_api_key": "API_KEY",
        })
        
print(llm)
```

**Output:**

```bash
OpenAIChat[Params: {'model_name': 'gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct', 'temperature': 0.0, 'top_p': 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating the LangChain to 0.1.0 (the current latest version).